# Auctex imenu add frames to list?

Tags: auctex, beamer, imenu

I use imenu in auctex. For beamer slides, it only offers me the `\section`-commands as entry points. How can I teach imenu to also offer all frames? (Which is an environment: `\begin{frame}....\end{frame}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make AUCTeX aware of the frame environment, i.e., `\frametitle`:

```
(add-to-list 'TeX-outline-extra '("\\\\frametitle\\b" 4))
```

From the documentation on `Tex-outline-extra`:

> List of extra TeX outline levels.
>
> Each element is a list with two entries.  The first entry is the
>   regular expression matching a header, and the second is the level of
>   the header.  See ‘LaTeX-section-list’ for existing header levels.

Similarly, you need to explicitely tell reftex to show `\frametitle` in its TOC:

```
(setq reftex-section-levels '(("part" . 0)
                              ("chapter" . 1)
                              ("section" . 2)
                              ("subsection" . 3)
                              ("subsubsection" . 4)
                              ("frametitle" . -3)
                              ("paragraph" . 5)
                              ("subparagraph" . 6)
                              ("addchap" . -1)
                              ("addsec" . -2)))
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! But I use frame environments. I tried: `(add-to-list 'TeX-outline-extra '("\\\\begin{frame}{\\(.*?\\)}" 4))`. The result is a list with items all named 'frame', and they all point to the first frame. So how can I tell imenu which part of the regexp contains the header name? And how do I teach imenu to jump to the corrseponding line?

Comment: If you instead use `(add-to-list 'TeX-outline-extra '("\\\\begin{frame}\\(\\[.*\\]\\)?" 4))` the entries in imenu will point to different frames. Still their title doesn't show up there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept that answer. The solution still is not perfect, maybe someone finds out how to add the frame title to the imenu listing.

Answer (score 0):

I use some dummy commands to mark my outline. The solution is not perfect, but it is usable.

I configure `TeX-outline-extra` this way:

```
(add-to-list 'TeX-outline-extra '("imenu" 1))
(add-to-list 'TeX-outline-extra '("imenuOne" 1))
(add-to-list 'TeX-outline-extra '("imenuTwo" 2))
(add-to-list 'TeX-outline-extra '("imenuThree" 3))
(add-to-list 'TeX-outline-extra '("imenuFour" 4))
```

In my `tex` file I add:

```
\newcommand{\imenu}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\imenuOne}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\imenuTwo}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\imenuThree}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\imenuFour}[1]{#1}
```

Now I can add an outline level anywhere, like this:

```
\begin{homeworkProblem}[\imenu{The first problem}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is more than 2 years old, but I had the same question myself, and none of the above answers worked for me. Here's the workaround I used.

I think auctex sets `imenu-create-index-function` to `LaTeX-imenu-create-index-function`. In my LaTeX-mode-hook, I reset it as shown below and use a variant of the regexps given in the answers above.

```
(setq-local imenu-create-index-function
            'imenu-default-create-index-function)
(setq-local imenu-generic-expression
                    '((nil ; put in top-level menu
                       "^\\\\begin{frame}\\(\\[[a-z,]+\\]\\)?{\\(.+\\)}"
                       2   ; which bracketed expression goes in title
                       )))
```

Now my imenu shows the frame titles as entries.